# Exclude array from array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to simply exclude some array elements from another array and get the result using js and jQuery. I find my self doing a double .each() loop...

```
var exclude = new Array();
exclude = [1,2,3,4];
var original = new Array();
original = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var finalarray = excludearrayfunction(original, exclude); // [0,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## jQuery [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

You can use the jQuery [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude items from a collection like so:

```
var exclude = [1,2,3,4];
var original = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var result = $(original).not(exclude);
```

This will return us a jQuery object, to select the result as an array we can simply do:

```
var finalArray = result.get();
// result: 0,5,6,7,8
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JgH6t/)

### Complete

```
var exclude = [1,2,3,4];
var original = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var finalArray = $(original).not(exclude).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var exclude = [1,2,3,4];
var original = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var finalarray = $.grep(original,function(el,i) {
  return !~$.inArray(el,exclude);
});
```

`!~` is a shortcut for seeing if a value is equal to -1, and if $.inArray(el,exclude) returns -1, you know the value in the original array is not in the exclude array, so you keep it.

Comment: `~` is a bitwise NOT operator which takes a value and flips each binary bit. we can use it in special cases like this because only `~(-1)` returns `0`, and `!0 == true`, so writing `!~(x)` is the same as `(x) === -1`

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.difference = function(arr) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return arr.indexOf(i) < 0; });
};
```

Comment: modifying prototypes for native objects is generally not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this and its better for perf.

```
finalArray = [];
orig = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
exclude = [1,2,3,4];

orig.forEach(function(x) { if (exclude[x] === undefined) { finalArray.push(x) }}); 
//[0,5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function excludearrayfunction(original, exclude) {
  var temp = [];
  $.each(original, function(i, val) {
      if( $.inArray( val, exclude) != -1 ) {
        temp.push(val);
      }
  });
  return temp;
}
```

***OR***

```
function excludearrayfunction(original, exclude) {
   return $.grep(original, function(i, val) {
      return $.inArray(exclude, val) != -1;
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.not`. You can find it [here](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
var original = [1,2,3];
var exclude = [1,2];

var tempArr = $(original).not(exclude);


var finalArray = tempArr .get();
```